# How do I move and rename files in dockerswarm

Tags: docker-swarm

I am logged in as root

the file is config.jason is in ***~/.docker*** directory and i just want to move it to the root folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand the problem, but I will try to answer what I think you might be looking for.

Whenever you want to change any settings/files/information from the docker & docker/swarm files/folders you should stop the docker service, do the changes in config and such and then start the service back again.

For instance adjusting the /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
# make the changes
sudo service docker start
```

In case you want to MOVE any actual files or switch directories I personally use rsync to do so, which works GREAT.

Example:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rsync -aP /var/lib/docker/ /opt/docker
sudo service docker start
```

Hope it helps